# Trigger.io and Backbone.js

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, trigger.io

Just wondering if Trigger.io and Backbone.js play nicely? I am going to write my first app using Trigger.io and wondering if I would be complicating the process by using backbone. The backend to my Trigger.io app will be Rails, and I've used Backbone.js with Rails and it's not bad. Any tutorials or advice you could provide would be cool, thanks!

Comment: I can set up a trigger.io + backbone.js template project on github... as well as a trigger.io + backbone.js + jquery mobile template project on github.

Comment: @Kris Krause that's be cool update me with the repo i'll definitely take a look

Comment: which?  trigger.io + backbone.js?  Or trigger.io + backbone.js + jqm?

Comment: i'd be interested in looking at either... thanks. feel free to personal message me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes trigger.io and backbone.js work fine.  In fact, the default trigger.io template app it creates for you uses it.  Here is a recent app that is live in the app stores that utilize backbone.js and trigger.io -

https://github.com/dragthor/south-ridge-app

Good luck.  And keep us posted on how your app develops.

Here is another example app -

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/best_practice/example_project.html

Comment: where is the "default trigger.io template app"?

Comment: mkdir "your-app"... cd "your-app"... forge create.  It then creates a default application for you.

Comment: Small note - our default app is actually just jQM now, although we do have a little Backbone demo here https://github.com/trigger-corp/Forge-Bootstrap

Comment: @JamesBrady - today the first thing I do is remove JQM.  Personal preference.